# Кастомизированные селекты

Tags: javascript, html, css, select

Есть тестовое задание, сверстать небольшую страницу, одной из задач по js является: (дословно) кастомизированные селекты + картинка ниже.

Я человек в кодинге не очень опытный, поэтому не знаю что толком можно сделать.
Прошу совета профи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Могу порекомендовать свой :) [Vanilla Javascript Select](http://zoltantothcom.github.io/vanilla-js-select/) - чистый JS, никаких зависимостей, практически ничего не весит, пример использования приведен там же :)

Comment: Еще кастомный http://jsbin.com/sozipol/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Никто не говорит, что можно вообще сделать в селектах(((

Comment: http://dimox.name/jquery-form-styler/ вот, но блин проще самому сделать

Comment: Проще, когда ты на "ты" с кодом))) Я пока что не достиг дзена.

Comment: Стилизовать сам селект с помощью css - невозможно

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/ или http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/ вот с помощью этого вещаешь обработчики событий на ul и крутишь баранку

Comment: Я бы посоветовал стандартные контролы (select и input с type=date) и стилизовать их через CSS, тогда ими будет легко и комфортно пользоваться с мобильных устройств.

Comment: @SurfinBird, "(select и input с type=date) и стилизовать их через CSS" а как их можно привести к такому виду как на картинке при помощи css? Просто интересно.

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, для webkit нужно сбросить стандартный вид с «-webkit-appearance:none», а затем можно менять фон, границы, стрелку вниз (с background-image с правого края). Только вот если цвет текста будет белым, нужно будет не забыть добавить «option{color:#000}». Вот [куча различных вариаций](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZpVYyd).

Comment: И скудная поддержка браузерами!!

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю, что смысл задания, скорее всего, именно в реализации кастомного поведения в браузере, техники получения атрибутов, установки `value` итп. Или, возможно - техники кроссбраузерной стилизации нативного селектора. А способов сделать "декоратор" селекта - чрезвычайно много,  даже если не брать готовые библиотеки. Выбор способа зависит от пути реализации фронтенда, принятого на проекте. Необходимость же в кастомных селектах существует, т.к. встроенные в браузер селекторы плохо стилизуются браузерами, но универсального решения, покрывающего все кейсы, не существует. Суть техники заключается в моделировании селектора посредством `<div />`, `<span />` и `<input />` и маппинге соответствующих событий и свойств оригинального элемента. Обычно есть цель устанавливать поля соответствующей формы. Основной способ передачи данных - атрибуты и свойства оригинального `<select>`, который, как-правило, скрыт. Есть вероятность, что нужна реализация мульти-селектора. Вобщем, у этой задачи есть несколько уровней сложности и возможной проработки. Готовые решения, с другой стороны, добавляют свой уровень сложности и в CSS и в скриптах, осбенно, если инстансов много и у каждого сложное поведение.